# Show error from save_post in Post Editing/Adding Wordpress 5.0

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-gutenberg

[image]

In that green success section, wordpress will show a red error if there is an error.  Id like to hook into that from my save_post php action when there is an error with my own custom text.  is that possible?